# Why am I getting a "permission denied" error with this Perl CGI script?

Tags: apache, perl, ubuntu, scripting, cgi

I am trying to make a Perl script that takes a remote host's IP address when they visit a certain website. However I can't seem to get past this apache error:

`Permission denied at path_to_perl_script line 19`

I am running a website on an Ubuntu server and I have configured Apache2 and CGI properly.

Here is the `login.pl` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T
use CGI;
use DBI;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Path::Class;
use autodie;    

# read the CGI params
my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $username = $cgi->param("username");
my $password = $cgi->param("password");

my $port = $cgi->remote_host();

my $dir = dir("var/www/html");
my $file = dir->file("testingPerl.txt");
my $file_handle = $file->openw();
$file_handle->print($port);
```

I am fairly new to Perl and I don't quite understand why I am getting this error.

Comment: This is the only perl script I made, so.....@zdim

Comment: I understand @zdim, but the script above is "login.pl", sorry for the confusion I have updated the question to say that this is that file. Otherwise I don't know where the error could be coming from...

Comment: Okay, better? @zdim, Should I add anything to make it more clear?

Comment: I suggest that we tidy up and remove these comments which aren't of any use anymore (the first two and the last two, perhaps?).  When you hover the mouse over your comment it shows a little cross, and if you click on it the comment is deleted (with a confirmation dialog first).

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Yes, firstly, I will try to write to a file, however, everytime I try that, with the updated code in the question, I get a permission denied error in the apache error.log. I've been reading some threads on this issue and apparently changing the permissions with "chmod" won't solve this. Any ideas @zdim?

Comment: That was the old error @PerlDog, the updated error is listed afterwards

Comment: @M.Barbieri  OK, this is better.  Please note that by changing the post so much all my comments (and other people's efforts who simply may have not commented) got completely invalidated.  (So I removed them.) Not a criticism, just letting you know for the future. Editing the question to clarify is great, but if it morphs into something else that's different.

Comment: @zdim, I apologize, thank you for the advice. As I am relatively new to perl, I can get carried away in going error by error on my log and posting it here, so I can see where that could get confusing. Thank you for all the help though!

Comment: @M.Barbieri No problem at all, it's clear that you put an effort in and tried.  It's almost an art form, posting effectively.  I still struggle.  The only way I know of is to think/work through the question to be posted carefully.  Then there's a good chance that the post will be nice and only need small adjustments or clarifications.

Comment: @M.Barbieri  To repeat my early remark -- it would be good to tidy up this thread of comments.  All of those before PerlDog's comment are now outdated and only make this page harder to look at.  Let's remove them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting a "permission denied" error because of this statement:

```
my $dir = dir("var/www/html");
```

The path `var/www/html` is relative to the script's current working directory and it is unlikely that it exsits. What you likely want is `/var/www/html`.

However, your script runs with the privileges of the user id under which the web server is running. In normal configurations, that user often is not allowed to write to `/var/www/html`. So, fixing that may not fix your problem.

Further, note that you don't need or want autodie if you use [Path::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Class) or [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny): They both croak on error.

You can try this simple script to see if everything is working:

```
#!/path/to/perl -T

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $cgi = CGI->new;
print $cgi->header('text/plain'), $cgi->remote_host, "\n";
```

Finally, it looks like you are going to overwrite the output file for each visitor.